# slide UITableView left when disclosure button clicked

Tags: animation, uitableview

I have a UITableView with cells that contain a disclosure button. Is there a way built in to slide another UITableView from right to left when clicked?

Or do I have create my own animation block?

Comment: Try pushing a UITableViewController or add tableView in a view and animate it by setting frame from right end to left end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meeras answer was correct. I simply add the view.